# Magento2 adding bundle product to existing quote not working

Tags: magento2, admin, cart, quote, bundle-product

I want to add bundle product with its required options in existing quote in admin,i have added following code to add products to existing quote, its working fine for simple product but bundle products not adding to cart unfortunately, can anyone help me how to achieve this? here is my code:

```
$qty = 1;
$quote = $this->quoteFactory->create()->load($quote->getId());
$product = $this->productRepository->getById($product->getId());
$quote->addProduct($product, $qty);
$quote->save();
```

Comment: You need to specify his diffrent options with this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do code like this one.

```
$qty = 1;
$quote = $this->quoteFactory->create()->load($quote->getId());
$product = $this->productRepository->getById($product->getId());
$magentooptions = array(5=>"1",23=>"2",32=>"3");
$par = array('product' => $product->getId(),
             'bundle_options' => array(1 => $magentooptions),
             'qty' => $qty);
$quote->addProduct($product, $par);
$quote->save();
```

`$magentooptions` parameters 5,23,32 are child product ids associated with this main bundle product.

Or you can use this code :

```
    $quote = $this->quoteFactory->create()->load($quote->getId());
    $product = $this->productRepository->getById($product->getId());
    $par = array('product' => $product->getId(),
            'qty' => 1
    );
    $selectionCollection = $product->getTypeInstance(true)
            ->getSelectionsCollection(
                $product->getTypeInstance(true)->getOptionsIds($product),
                $product
            );
            foreach ($selectionCollection as $proselection) {
                $par['bundle_option'][$proselection->getOptionId()] = $proselection->getSelectionId();
            }

    $quote->addProduct($product, $par);
    $quote->save();
```

Comment: Hello @dhiren, thanks for reply, what is 1,2 and 3 within 5=>"1",23=>"2",32=>"3" and 'bundle_options' => array(1 => $magentooptions) with this 1 is the key is fixed? can you please tell? and i assume these child product ids must exist in that bundle product

Comment: Yes you need to replace above id with his real Id of the options.

Comment: $quote->addProduct($product, $par);
this is not working, when i add this code nothing adds to quote but when i use below code it adds only simple products except bundle products:
$quote->addProduct($product, $qty);

Comment: i have actually 3 simple products and 1 bundle products right now so i wanted to add bundle product in quote

Comment: Yes, but into bundle product, you assign some simple product, which Id you want to pass here, which you want to add.

Comment: i already have added it here is my parameter array you can check:
<pre>Array
(
    [product] => 2821
    [qty] => 1
    [bundle_options] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [2824] => 1
                    [2301] => 2
                    [2801] => 3
                )

        )

)
also in that bundle products those product ids available.

Comment: Did you face any issue now?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99418/discussion-between-bhargav-shastri-and-dhiren-vasoya).